# Tcolorbox overzoom position

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox

I'd like to know, would it be possible to change the position of a picture that is defined in a `tcolorbox` with for example `fill overzoom image`, or `watermark` ? By default, the image is centered, but I'd like to be able to choose if I put it on the right, left, or center it.

Thank you !

Example :

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{simpson}

By default the focus is on the middle part...
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=7cm,height=7cm,interior style={fill overzoom image=simpson}]
\end{tcolorbox}
% And now I'd like to say please, focus on the right part,
% on the left part, or go 80% on the right...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the starred version of the key to pass options to includegraphics and so use trim or viewport:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-A}


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5cm,height=5cm,
       interior style={fill overzoom image*={trim=4cm 4cm 0cm 0cm}{example-image-A}}]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5cm,height=5cm,
       interior style={fill overzoom image*={viewport= 5cm 1cm 10cm 10cm}{example-image-A}}]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]